# Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed when using internal class in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-c++, this

I am having a class scanner where a device message is declared internal like this see. This is scanner.h file code:

```
#pragma once
class CScanner
{
public:
    CScanner(void);


    class CDeviceMessage;

    ~CScanner(void);
};
```

Problem occurs in device message class in its method there is error on this pointer. It says pointer to incomplete class type not allowed CDeviceMessage.h.

The CDeviceMessage.h file code is here, I am not including complete code but function defination and declaration so you might understand it:

```
#pragma once
#include "Scanner.h"


class CScanner::CDeviceMessage
{

bool MatchesOtherMessage(CScanner::CDeviceMessage * other);

};
```

and CDeviceMessage.cpp function where error comes is this:

```
bool CScanner::CDeviceMessage::MatchesOtherMessage(CDeviceMessage *other)
{

    if (other != NULL)
            {
                if ((this->imgMessage != NULL) && (other->imgMessage != NULL))/// here it gives on this pointer error that pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
                {
                    int timeDiff = this->imgMessage->OnlineMilliseconds
                            - this->imgMessage->OnlineMilliseconds;
                    if ((timeDiff > -20) && (timeDiff < 40))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `CScanner::` prefix in front of `CDeviceMessage *other` in

```
bool CScanner::CDeviceMessage::MatchesOtherMessage(CDeviceMessage *other)
```

Comment: tell me another thing is there any issue in this line it is giving error : syntax error : 'constant' and line is:

static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 518400 + 400;//here is error

Comment: Well, is the original issue you reported solved ? With your other error, I cannot see anything wrong with the line you are giving me but it seens like you had written "constant" instead of "const".